# Values not being passed when I initiate a class

Tags: java, eclipse, class, initialization, switch-statement

I'm making an RPG Class builder that passes stat value's based on the item selected by the user, based off that choice a new instance of the class is made, however when I display the value's it's as if the value's were never passed.

Here is my code First the Class page, then a file to test and set the Class values:

```
    package com.polaris.mbti;

    public class MBTI_Type 
    {
       private int Se;
       private int Si;
       private int Ne;
       private int Ni;
       private int Te;
       private int Ti;
       private int Fe;
       private int Fi;
       private int Vitality;
       private int Durability;
       private int Strength;
       private int Tact;
       private int Loyalty;
       private int Friendliness;
       private int Ambition;
       private int Insight;
       private int Foresight;
       private int Humanity;
       private int Revelation;
       private int Charisma;
       private int Dexterity;
       private int Evasion;
       private int Accuracy;
       private int Agility;
       private int Zest;
       private int Grace;
       private int Intelligence;
       private int Curiousity;
       private int Analysis;
       private int Idealism;
       private int Enthusiasm;
       private int Conviction;
   public void setBaseStats(int introSen, int extroSen, int introThk, int extroThk, int introInuit, int extroInuit, int introFel, int extroFel)
   {
      Se = extroSen;
      Si = introSen;
      Ne = extroInuit;
      Ni = introInuit;
      Te = extroThk;
      Ti = introThk;
      Fe = extroFel;
      Fi = introFel;
      setMajorStats();
   }
   public void setMajorStats()
   {
      setMinorStats(Te, Si, Vitality, Durability, Strength);
      setMinorStats(Te, Ni, Ambition, Insight, Foresight);
      setMinorStats(Fe, Si, Tact, Loyalty, Friendliness);
      setMinorStats(Fe, Ni, Humanity, Revelation, Charisma);
      setMinorStats(Ti, Se, Dexterity, Evasion, Accuracy);
      setMinorStats(Ti, Ne, Intelligence, Curiousity, Analysis);
      setMinorStats(Fi, Se, Agility, Zest, Grace);
      setMinorStats(Fi, Ne, Idealism, Enthusiasm, Conviction);
  }
  public void setMinorStats(double A, double B, double Major, double MinorA, double MinorB)
  {
      Major = (A + B)/2;
      if(A > B)
      {
          MinorA = (Major) - 1;
          MinorB = (Major) + 1;
      }
      if(B > A)
      {
          MinorA = (Major) + 1;
          MinorB = (Major) - 1;
      }
  }
  public void levelUp()
  {

  }
  public void showStats()
  {
     System.out.println(Vitality);
     System.out.println(Durability);
     System.out.println(Strength);
     System.out.println(Tact);
     System.out.println(Loyalty);
     System.out.println(Friendliness);
     System.out.println(Ambition);
     System.out.println(Insight);
     System.out.println(Foresight);
     System.out.println(Humanity);
     System.out.println(Revelation);
     System.out.println(Charisma);
     System.out.println(Dexterity);
     System.out.println(Evasion);
     System.out.println(Accuracy);
     System.out.println(Agility);
     System.out.println(Zest);
     System.out.println(Grace);
     System.out.println(Intelligence);
     System.out.println(Curiousity);
     System.out.println(Analysis);
     System.out.println(Idealism);
     System.out.println(Enthusiasm);
     System.out.println(Conviction);
  }


 }
```

Here is the class with a main method for testing it:

```
package com.polaris.mbti;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMBTI2 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a personality type from the choices:");
    System.out.println(" 1  - ESTJ");
    System.out.println(" 2  - ENTJ");
    System.out.println(" 3  - ISTP");
    System.out.println(" 4  - INTP");
    System.out.println(" 5  - ESFJ");
    System.out.println(" 6  - ENFJ");
    System.out.println(" 7  - ISFP");
    System.out.println(" 8  - INFP");
    System.out.println(" 9  - ESTP");
    System.out.println(" 10 - ESFP");
    System.out.println(" 11 - ISTJ");
    System.out.println(" 12 - ISFJ");
    System.out.println(" 13 - ENTP");
    System.out.println(" 14 - ENFP");
    System.out.println(" 15 - INTJ");
    System.out.println(" 16 - INFJ");
    int choice = inputDevice.nextInt();

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        MBTI_Type ESTJ = new MBTI_Type();
        ESTJ.setBaseStats(14, 6, 8, 16, 4, 12, 10, 2);
        ESTJ.showStats();
        break;
    case 2:
        MBTI_Type ENTJ = new MBTI_Type();
        ENTJ.setBaseStats(4, 12, 8, 16, 14, 6, 10, 2);
        ENTJ.showStats();
        break;
    case 3:
        MBTI_Type ISTP = new MBTI_Type();
        ISTP.setBaseStats(6, 14, 16, 8, 12, 4, 2, 10);
        ISTP.showStats();
        break;
    case 4:
        MBTI_Type INTP = new MBTI_Type();
        INTP.setBaseStats(12, 4, 16, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10);
        INTP.showStats();
        break;
    case 5:
        MBTI_Type ESFJ = new MBTI_Type();
        ESFJ.setBaseStats(14, 6, 10, 2, 4, 12, 8, 16);
        ESFJ.showStats();
        break;
    case 6:
        MBTI_Type ENFJ = new MBTI_Type();
        ENFJ.setBaseStats(4, 12, 10, 2, 14, 6, 16, 8);
        ENFJ.showStats();
        break;
    case 7:
        MBTI_Type ISFP = new MBTI_Type();
        ISFP.setBaseStats(6, 14, 2, 10, 12, 4, 16, 8);
        ISFP.showStats();
        break;
    case 8:
        MBTI_Type INFP = new MBTI_Type();
        INFP.setBaseStats(12, 4, 2, 10, 6, 14, 16, 8);
        INFP.showStats();
        break;
    case 9:
        MBTI_Type ESTP = new MBTI_Type();
        ESTP.setBaseStats(8, 16, 14, 6, 10, 2, 4, 12);
        ESTP.showStats();
        break;
    case 10:
        MBTI_Type ESFP = new MBTI_Type();
        ESFP.setBaseStats(8, 16, 4, 12, 10, 2, 14, 6);
        ESFP.showStats();
        break;
    case 11:
        MBTI_Type ISTJ = new MBTI_Type();
        ISTJ.setBaseStats(16, 8, 6, 14, 2, 10, 12, 4);
        ISTJ.showStats();
        break;
    case 12:
        MBTI_Type ISFJ = new MBTI_Type();
        ISFJ.setBaseStats(16, 8, 12, 4, 2, 10, 6, 14);
        ISFJ.showStats();
        break;
    case 13:
        MBTI_Type ENTP = new MBTI_Type();
        ENTP.setBaseStats(10, 2, 14, 6, 8, 16, 4, 12);
        ENTP.showStats();
        break;
    case 14:
        MBTI_Type ENFP = new MBTI_Type();
        ENFP.setBaseStats(10, 2, 4, 12, 8, 16, 14, 6);
        ENFP.showStats();
        break;
    case 15:
        MBTI_Type INTJ = new MBTI_Type();
        INTJ.setBaseStats(2, 10, 6, 14, 16, 8, 12, 4);
        INTJ.showStats();
        break;
    case 16:
        MBTI_Type INFJ = new MBTI_Type();
        INFJ.setBaseStats(2, 10, 12, 4, 16, 8, 14, 6);
        INFJ.showStats();
        break;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems likely to be with `setMinorStats` method. From the implementation, it seems it's calculating some values. However, those values are not set to the object (i.e. there is no `this.something = value` assignments).

The method modifes the values of parameters passed, however it won't change the actual values because of Java being `pass by value`. I would recommend having a look at [these](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) examples.

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle when debugging, stick in a default value and see if that come up, then youll know if your program isnt getting to the switch at all, or is just not recognising any if the values you have.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never actually set any of the attributes that you are printing (Vitality, Durability, etc).

Did you mean to set them in setMinorStats()?

At in the if statements of your setMinorStats() method, add something to this effect

`this.Vitality = Major;`

If you replace your method with mine below, and run with keyboard input of 1 for first case, you will see that Vitality is set to 8 when it outputs.

```
public void setMinorStats(double A, double B, double Major, double MinorA, double MinorB)
  {
      Major = (A + B)/2;
      if(A > B)
      {
          MinorA = (Major) - 1;
          MinorB = (Major) + 1;

          /*
           * Here is what you need to do-- set your fields based on your logic
           */
          this.Vitality = (int)Major;
      }
      if(B > A)
      {
          MinorA = (Major) + 1;
          MinorB = (Major) - 1;
      }
  }
```

Comment: When I call that method the other stats are calculated based on the eight base stats. That method calls another, which calls another.

Comment: No, there are no function calls in the setMinorStats() method, nor do you set the values that you are printing. As Darshan says in his answer, the parameters that you pass to setMinorStats() are `by value`, rather than by reference, meaning you don't affect the class fields (Vitality, etc.).

Comment: Replace your setMinorStats() with mine, and run with keyboard input of 1 to test the first case. Notice that in my code, the Vitality field is now set to 8 on output.

Comment: That seems good but the method is suppose to set more stats then just vitality is there a way to do the this.Stat = int(Major); Without having to do a this method for every stat the point of the method was to automate the stat setting instead of doing them all myself.

Comment: To modify the values in the way that you wish, you will need to pass the arguments to setMinorStats by reference. To do that in java, you will need to declare your class fields as objects (Integer, Double, etc, rather than primitives like double, int, etc). IMO, this is a bad solution. It requires much more memory space, and will require you to modify each of your operations on these fields to methods that are supported by their object classes. In other words, this IS the automation code.

Comment: Never mind I found a different way I just return the value calculated in the method and assign that to Vitality, and just use methods that return. I'll post my solution.

Comment: So you decided to make the assignments outside of the method instead. Good work, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to my problem, I simply split my method into three others and made them have return statements as seen below.

```
public void setBaseStats(int introSen, int extroSen, int introThk, int extroThk, int introInuit, int extroInuit, int introFel, int extroFel)
{
    Se = extroSen;
    Si = introSen;
    Ne = extroInuit;
    Ni = introInuit;
    Te = extroThk;
    Ti = introThk;
    Fe = extroFel;
    Fi = introFel;
    setMajorStats();
}
public void setMajorStats()
{
    Vitality = setMinorStats(Te, Si);
    Durability = setMinorStatsA(Vitality, Te, Si);
    Strength = setMinorStatsB(Vitality, Te, Si);
    Ambition = setMinorStats(Te, Ni);
    Insight = setMinorStatsA(Ambition, Te, Ni);
    Foresight = setMinorStatsB(Ambition, Te, Ni);
    Tact = setMinorStats(Fe, Si);
    Loyalty = setMinorStatsA(Tact, Fe, Si);
    Friendliness = setMinorStatsB(Tact, Fe, Si);
    Humanity = setMinorStats(Fe, Ni);
    Revelation = setMinorStatsA(Humanity, Fe, Ni);
    Charisma = setMinorStatsB(Humanity, Fe, Ni);
    Dexterity = setMinorStats(Ti, Se);
    Evasion = setMinorStatsA(Dexterity, Ti, Se);
    Accuracy = setMinorStatsB(Dexterity, Ti, Se);
    Intelligence = setMinorStats(Ti, Ne);
    Curiousity = setMinorStatsA(Intelligence, Ti, Ne);
    Analysis =setMinorStatsB(Intelligence, Ti, Ne);
    Agility = setMinorStats(Fi, Se);
    Zest = setMinorStatsA(Agility, Fi, Se);
    Grace = setMinorStatsB(Agility, Fi, Se);
    Idealism = setMinorStats(Fi, Ne);
    Enthusiasm = setMinorStatsA(Idealism, Fi, Ne);
    Conviction = setMinorStatsB(Idealism, Fi, Ne);
}
public int setMinorStats(int A, int B)
{
    int Major = (A + B)/2;
    return Major;
}
public int setMinorStatsA(int Major, int A, int B)
{
    int MinorA = 0;
    if(A > B)
        MinorA = (Major) - 1;
    if(B > A)
        MinorA = (Major) + 1;
    return MinorA;
}
public int setMinorStatsB(int Major, int A, int B)
{
    int MinorB = 0;
    if(A > B)
        MinorB = (Major) + 1;
    if(B > A)
        MinorB = (Major) - 1;
    return MinorB;
}
```